# How can you change an Ethernet connection to a connection with an external Wi-Fi adapter?

Tags: wireless-networking, ethernet, kali-linux, usb-network-adapter

I was trying to execute `airmon-ng` and `airodump-ng` commands in Kali Linux virtual machine, and then figured out that since my laptop had an in-built Ethernet port, the terminal couldn't detect any type of internet connection.

So I bought a USB network adapter, only to figure out that even if you connect it to the laptop, the computer would still work in an ethernet port way, **not** in a `wlan0` way.

Is there any way for the USB adapter to function properly?

Comment: Have you tried Virt-manager and tried to use the phsyical wifi adapter? worth a shot. virt-manager is the vm you gotta put kali on that. the menu should have some options to use the wifi adapater

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your Virtual Machine App supports USB Pass Through.

VMware Workstation does for sure. I think Virtual Box does as well. Hyper-V only supports Pass Through for Generation 2 machines (not Gen 1) and then it is picky to set up.

Set up USB Pass Through, and try to install your Wireless Card (install the Linux driver for it). Once installed and working, you can disconnect the Ethernet connection.

Not all cards work with Kali.  So if your card does not work (that is does not install), look for "Kali supported wireless cards"

I am in Kali 2023.2 now and I have a Panda Wireless PUA08 and that definitely works with a Kali VM (VMware Workstation) and I use it. The Panda PUA08 supports Monitor Mode, so the air... commands you want do work.

Answer (score 0):

check this out on how to pass a wifi usb card to kali in hyperv or any other hypervisor  https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/kali-hyper-v-usb-wifi-card-passthrough-mihai-t%C4%83lm%C4%83cel/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).